# Problem with Rate function

Tags: php

## Short description:

The rate function calculates the rate neccessary to reach the future value.

nper - number of periods (number of periods)
pmt  - payments (every month or year)
pv   - present value (the initial amount)
fv   - future value (the amount to reach)

## Question:

I have used the funtion Rate (php code below) and i have some troubles with it.  I use it with the following values:

### Wrong

```
 Excel - RATE(228;-196,02;-49005;961546,464646;1;0,05) gives: 0,0119
 Php   - RATE(228,-196.02,-49005,961546.464646,1,0.05) gives: 0.0022
```

### Good

```
 Excel - RATE(228;-196,02;-49005;161546,464646;1;0,05) gives:0,003
 Php   - RATE(228,-196.02,-49005,161546.464646,1,0.05) gives:0.003
```

It looks like that when the difference between `$nper`, `$pv`, `$pmt` and `$fv` becomes bigger the code goes wrong.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

```
define('FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS', 128);
define('FINANCIAL_PRECISION', 1.0e-08);


function rate($nper, $pmt, $pv, $fv, $type, $guess) 
{

    $rate = $guess;
    if (abs($rate) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION) {
        $y = $pv * (1 + $nper * $rate) + $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * $nper + $fv;
    } else {
        $f = exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
        $y = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;
    }
    $y0 = $pv + $pmt * $nper + $fv;
    $y1 = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;

    // find root by secant method
    $i  = $x0 = 0.0;
    $x1 = $rate;
    while ((abs($y0 - $y1) > FINANCIAL_PRECISION) && ($i < FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS)) {
        $rate = ($y1 * $x0 - $y0 * $x1) / ($y1 - $y0);
        $x0 = $x1;
        $x1 = $rate;

        if (abs($rate) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION) {
            $y = $pv * (1 + $nper * $rate) + $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * $nper + $fv;
        } else {
            $f = exp($nper * log(1 + $rate));
            $y = $pv * $f + $pmt * (1 / $rate + $type) * ($f - 1) + $fv;
        }

        $y0 = $y1;
        $y1 = $y;
        ++$i;
    }
    return $rate;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better provide some short description, what your rate function is intended to do. It's hard to tell it from the code. Also, [PHP's statistics functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php) might be helpful . And [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) could shed some light on the problem

Comment: You are right. Next time i will do that. I don't know how to edit the call. Regards Hans

Comment: Is that `Rate` function is domain-specific, or there is some widely-used algorithm?

Comment: It is a widely used algorithm. I found this version on this website.

Answer (score 0):

The code is using the secant method to find the rate of return, I am not sure why the code is not working properly but a better way to implement the Excel RATE function is done with Newton Raphson Method

I will give you the equation that Excel uses for the TVM functions and you can implement the Newton Raphson method by making function f(x) out of this equation

From there you will need to get a derivative of f(x) namely f'(x) and follow the instructions on this page about [IRR](http://njinstruments.com/). The page describes finding IRR with Newton Raphson method but you can replace function f(x) and f'(x) in the article with the following function

```
f(x) = PV (1+RATE)^NPER + PMT(1+RATE*TYPE)[{(1+RATE)^NPER-1}/RATE] + FV
```

Now it is up to you to find f'(x) and use the steps outline for using the Newton Raphson Method

This Excel [RATE calculator](http://thinkanddone.com/finance/online-excel-rate-formula-calculator.html) is implemented in PHP using Newton Raphson method so you can use your test data to see if you get the required results. Do note that this calculator follows the US and UK notation for numbers and period is used to represent decimal point unlike the comma used in Europe